How do you deal with target image boundaries in direct image alignment?
In direct image alignment, given a set of points $x_{\\{M\\}}$ that appear in a template $T_1$ and image $I_2$, the pose can be found by minimizing the photometric error $E(x_{\\{M\\}})$.
\begin{equation}
E(x_{\\{M\\}}) = \sum_i^M | I_2 (W(x_i;p)) - T_1 (x_i) |^2_2 
\end{equation}
Warp function $W(x_i;p)$ warps image coordinates $x_i$ from the system of $T_k$ to that of $I_2$. This can be minimized with e.g. the inverse compositional algorithm.
My question is, how do people usually treat warped coordinates that fall outside of the frame of $I_2$? This is dependent on the transform, but of course that's what you're trying to estimate. Is it a matter of simply selecting point neighborhoods to compare that fall in the interior of $T_1$, so that the warped coordinates will fall within the bounds of $I_2$?
